# Killing a process does not actually kill it in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to kill the database running in my server using kill -9 PID, after killing that if i see the process running,database it still running with another PID, how can i actually kill it

Comment: can you check the parent process that could be re-spawning the process when killed

Comment: What exact Linux distribution, what concrete database system, are you talking about? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: "running with another PID". So `kill` did actually kill the process you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Specially for a database daemon, you should *never* kill it with `kill -9` a.k.a. `kill -KILL`, because when you have killed it with `SIGKILL` the underlying data files would be in an inconsistent state (so with bad luck you could lose all your databases!). To kill such a process, you really should use `kill -TERM` or `kill -QUIT` because the database code is very likely to handle those signals appropriately (by leaving data files in a consistent state). Remember that the `SIGKILL` [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) cannot be caught. Apparently, that daemon is restarted by the system script starting it (or by some [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or other [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)).

We don't know what DBMS you are talking about and what Linux distribution you have, but very likely your system have some command to stop the DBMS properly, e.g. `/etc/rc.d/mysql stop` or [mysqladmin shutdown](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html) or [pg_ctl stop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-ctl.html) or whatever.

Comment: i tried service mysql stop, it did it

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that. And show what happened. Of course you need to be root.